# Different menu for different Fragment Tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, menu

Description:
1) I have an Activity which contains one fragment. I replace sometimes this fragment with a menu. (First Level)
2) One of thus fragments is an tabFragments. It contains one fragments but this fragment can be replace when user click on a tab. (Second level)

I use Android over 4.0.

My question is:
How can I have "General" Menu for the RootActivity + a "Normal" Menu for my tabfragment + an other menu for my fragment inside the TabFragment, all in the ActionBar ?
In fact, when I switch between fragment in FirstLevel, menu is updated correctly, but when I go to the second level, menu keep item from an other second level Fragment. And when I come back to an other first level Fragments I still have menu from a second level fragment.

**Edit :**

First Level Fragment (TabFragment)

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_intervention, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        // Inflate Menu below;
    }
```

Second Level Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    // Inflate Menu below;
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_intervention_inventaire, menu);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible.

In your fragment's `onCreate` method call `setHasOptionsMenu(true)`. Do the same for your child fragment.

Then override `onCreateOptionsMenu` and `onOptionsItemSelected`.

Don't forget to call `super.onCreateOptionsMenu` from your fragments.

Put the common menu items in the Activity. And the other items in the appropriate fragment fragment.

Edit: You should use [ChildFragmentManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.html) for your child fragments. It's available in the support library.

Comment: yep, they all have setHasOptionsMenu(true) and I overrode onCreateOptionMenu and OnOptionsItemSelected. OnSelected works great but not onCreate.

Comment: What is the order super and inflate or inflate and super for you ?

Comment: can you post the code for onCreateOptionsMenu for your fragments?

Comment: also are you using ChildFragmentManager for the child fragments (level 2 fragments) ?

Comment: I can because i use Api16 and over and ChildFra... is Api17 and over, but maybe I can switch to Api17. I will see. I just edited my post

Comment: well that is your problem. Use ChildFragmentManager. It's backported to API4 in the Support Library. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.html

Comment: Ok I upgrade my app to Api 17 but still doesn't work

Comment: Sorry, IT WORKS, Thanks an lot. Can you edit your first answer with the solution and I will upvote and [Resolve] it ?